# Install IIS 8.5 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, iis, iis-8

Is it possible to install a IIS 8.5 on a Windows 10 machine?

I have to debut a site, and the IIS version that comes with Windows 10 (IIS 10) seems not be compatible with the sites configuration.

Comment: No;  IIS is an optional Windows Feature, which means IIS 8.5 isn't a feature of Windows 10 and cannot be installed on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this an ASP.net website?  The odds are that it is not an IIS issue, but a site configuration issue.

What are the issues you are facing exactly?  If you turn off friendly error messages - you will probably find either a 50x, 40x or similar error under the hood.

I say this because I have had to upgrade several developer machines from windows 7, 8.1 and even XP to windows 10 and every IIS problem they've hit ended up being the application pool missing, SQL misconfiguration, Application version (.net managed versions) or similar - So I know that if configured correctly - IIS on windows 10 can run anything that will execute on windows 8.1.

As for your request for info on how to install IIS 8.5 onto windows 10.  If you have some windows 8 media, there are a few blogs that say you can simply use DISM and point the command at some windows 8.1 install media for source files - but I just tried it on a windows 10 machine and it failed which leads me to believe this isn't possible.  You may also find that some library files (DLLs etc) which are installed with the role will conflict with the windows 10 versions as this is not a supported action.

Comment: perhaps you are right, but in order to be sure I wonder if is possible to install other IIS version that comes with the Windows...

Comment: Answer Ammended